# React Native - Navigation DrawerItem Label Multiline

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

In Sidebar I'm using "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5"

How to wrap the label in DrawlerItems to the next line?

```
const itemStyle = {
  marginLeft: 0,
  borderBottomColor: '#D9DBE9',
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  marginVertical: 0,
  paddingBottom: 10,
  paddingTop: 10,
  width: '100%',
};
```

```
const labelStyle = {
  fontSize: 16,
  fontWeight: '600'
}
```

```
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View>
    <DrawerItem
      label={'label 1'}
      labelStyle={{ ...labelStyle, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
      style={itemStyle}
    />
    <DrawerItem
      label={'long label 2'}
      labelStyle={{ ...labelStyle, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}
      style={itemStyle}
    />
  </View>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the because `DrawerItem` file has `numberOfLines={1}`

Workaround can be like you can update the [DrawerItem](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/drawer/src/views/DrawerItem.tsx) file from the library by removing [numberOfLines](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/5b13f818f3c701ce33c2a30f5dd96763069556e4/packages/drawer/src/views/DrawerItem.tsx#L193) Currently It has the following code

```
<Text
    numberOfLines={1} // this line making the label single liner
    allowFontScaling={allowFontScaling}
    style={[
      {
        color,
        fontWeight: "500",
      },
      labelStyle,
    ]}
  >
    {label}
</Text>
```

Alternate way is to use like function e.g

```
label={({focused, color}) => (
  <Text style={{color}}>Your Label</Text>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks, the label could be a function with a custom item ```label({ color, focused })```